# JSDOM in nodeJS: How do I get back the manipulated html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsdom

I am trying to manipulate a remote HTML and return it manipulated. I decided to use JSDOM but cannot figure out how to get the manipulated HTML back. Any ideas?

```
  jsdom.env({
        url: "http://www.cnn.com",
        scripts: ["http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"],
        done: function (err, window) {
            var $ = window.$;
            console.log("HN Links");
            var src = $(".ghciTopStoryImage1 img").attr('src','http://lorempixel.com/396/220/');
            var headline = $(".blkbigheader span").html('header');
            var description = $(".blkbigheader").parent().find("p a:eq(0)").html('text');

           // not working....
            content =$(window.document).html();

        }
    });
```

Comment: In something similar I used: `window.document.querySelector( 'html' ).outerHTML` to get the whole document.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[From the jsdom readme](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#serializing-the-document-with-serialize):

```
var JSDOM = require("jsdom").JSDOM;

var jsdom = new JSDOM("<!DOCTYPE html>hello");

jsdom.serialize() === "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>";
doc.documentElement.outerHTML === "<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>";
```

Adapting your above example would then just be `content = jsdom.serialize()`.

Answer (score 21):

sometimes jQuery isn't the answer

```
content = window.document.documentElement.outerHTML;
```

Comment: this will strip the doctype

Comment: easily added using `window.document.doctype`