# Serialializing an edited JSDOM document?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, jsdom

Attempting to write out an edited JSDOM instance using `document.toString` however it serializes as `[object Document]`.  What method should we call to get the document markup as a `String` or is there a better way to serialize it in node.  Currently I'm making this call:

```
     fs.writeFileSync(target, document.toString());
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31828568/jsdom-in-nodejs-how-do-i-get-back-the-manipulated-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation (https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom):

```
const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html>hello`);

dom.serialize() === "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>";

// Contrast with:
dom.window.document.documentElement.outerHTML === "<html><head></head><body>hello</body></html>";
```